# Close icon breaks in colorbox - Jquery colorbox

Tags: jquery, html, css, colorbox

I'm using color box. But the close icon breaks from the corner. Lets see the images.

[image: Close Icon]

See in the corner it gets broken. This happens with all the icons inside colorbox.

Here is the close button css & html seen with firebug.

```
<button id="cboxClose">close</button>

#cboxClose {
    background: url("../img/colorbox/controls.png") no-repeat scroll -25px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 25px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: 0;
    width: 25px;
}
```

controls.png file is like this

[image: controls.png]

How can I make the round shape exactly in the middle of the button or change this icon into a more beautiful one??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## cboxClose {

```
background: url("../img/colorbox/controls.png") no-repeat scroll -27px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
height: 25px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
text-indent: -9999px;
top: 0;
width: 25px;
```

}